# What do we call $P \rightarrow \lnot Q$?

Tags: proof-writing

Let us assume that we have a statement $P \rightarrow Q$. In this case, what would $P \rightarrow \lnot Q$ be called?

The reason why I want to know is that I want to show that $P$ is true by contradiction, proving that both $\lnot P \rightarrow \lnot Q$ and $\lnot P \rightarrow Q$ are true to conclude that $\lnot P$ is false. I initially framed this by stating that $\lnot P \rightarrow \lnot Q$ is a contradiction to $\lnot P \rightarrow Q$, but my supervisor said that this was incorrect, since both theorems are technically true.

Comment: $P\to\lnot Q$ is the same thing as $\lnot(P\wedge Q)$.

Comment: In computer science it is Nand(P,Q). That is, "not (P and Q)".

Comment: There are lots of names for statements related to implications, e.g. [inverse, converse, contrapositive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition#Comparisons), but this one does not seem to have a name.

Comment: "proving that both ¬P→Q and ¬P→Q are true to conclude that P is false" um.... huh?

Comment: Sorry, I meant "both $\lnot P \rightarrow Q$ and $\lnot P \rightarrow \lnot Q$".

Comment: " by stating that ¬P→¬Q is a contradiction to ¬P→Q"  Well that not a contradition.  They'll both be true if $P$ is true.  So that isn't a contradiction. (But if both statements are true that would be a way of showing P is true).

Comment: "Sorry, I meant "both ¬P→Q and ¬P→¬Q""  Did you also mean "P is **true**".  If $\lnot P \implies Q$ and $\lnot P\implies Q$ that (which is not a contradiction) would mean $\lnot P$ is false.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be no name for $P \rightarrow \lnot Q$.

The statement "$\neg P \to \neg Q$ is a contradiction to $\neg P \to Q$" is indeed wrong, since both these implications are true, they don't contradict each other.

The correct way to state this was to use modus ponens. You have already proven $\vdash \neg P \to \neg Q$ and $\vdash \neg P \to Q$. Since you assume $\neg P$, you then get $\vdash Q$ and $\vdash \neg Q$, and **this** is the contradiction you've been looking for.